# Atata: How to skip NoSuchElementException?

Tags: c#, atata

How to skip NoSuchElementException?

Or maybe can you elaborate how to initialize controls only before access them?

It doesn't work for me:

```
[FindByClass("profile"), WaitFor(on: TriggerEvents.BeforeAccess, ThrowOnAbsenceFailure = false)]
public UserProfileTile<TOwner> UserProfileTile { get; private set; }
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Your question needs clarification. What is the reason making the set method private? Your setter can't be accessed from outside, and that should be the reason for the exception.
And UserProfileTile is your type name and you also used it as the variable name try making it 

    public UserProfileTile<TOwner> userProfileTile { get; private set; }

or if you don't really need it to be private 

    public UserProfileTile<TOwner> userProfileTile { get; set; }

Comment: This is just an example. I mean that "TriggerEvents.BeforeAccess" and "ThrowOnAbsenceFailure" parameters don't work in my case (when I don't have element on the page and don't want to get NoSuchElementException)

Comment: Atata doesn't access control elements during initialization by default. You can get NoSuchElementException when you try to access this control, which in this case has no element found. If you need to check whether control's element exists, then UserProfileTile.IsPresent will give you true/false. And I assume that `WaitFor` is not needed at that property. Could you please clarify what you are doing with `UserProfileTile` and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with WaitFor attribute. I use it many times in different places. So, I cleaned properties and now everything works well. Thanks for help!